# Script says Undefined

Tags: javascript

I have this script that would let the user input a text and it would get translated into something else. It works only when the word has only 1 letter. When there is more than 1 letter it says Undefined.

Here is the script :

```
function copyit(theField) {
    var tempval = eval("document." + theField)
    tempval.focus()
    tempval.select()
    therange = tempval.createTextRange()
    therange.execCommand("Copy")
}

function results() {
    var behavior = "form";
    var text = document.csrAlpha.csrresult2.value;
    var ff22 = text.toLowerCase();
    var Words = new Array;
    Words["b"] = "Dadada";
    Words["bob"] = "Robert";
    Words["flower"] = "Banana";
    Words["brad"] = "Chair";
    var trans = "";
    var regExp = /[\!@#$%^&*(),=";:\/]/;
    var stringCheck = regExp.exec(ff22);
    if (!stringCheck) {
        if (ff22.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < ff22.length; i++) {
                var thisChar = ff22.charAt(i);
                trans += Words[thisChar] + " ";
            }
        } else {
            trans += "Please write something.";
        }
    } else {
        trans += "You entered invalid characters. Remove them and try again.";
    }
    document.csrAlpha.csrresult.value = trans;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" class="cleanuphtml-1">
      <form name="csrAlpha">
        Please insert your text below:<br />
        <input type="text" class="tb3" name="csrresult2" size="70" maxlength="120" autocomplete="off" onkeydown="results()" onkeyup="results()" onkeypress="return handleEnter(this, event);" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="csrAlpha.csrresult2.focus();" />

        <p>
          <textarea name="csrresult" class="tb7" cols="71" rows="10" value=""></textarea>
        </p>
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you please not quadruple space your code?

Comment: my apologies, I'll change that right now.

Comment: Not trying to be mean ;) It's just hard to read.

Comment: Just a tip, `var tempval=eval("document."+theField)` is the same as `var tempval = document[theField]`. You never really need to use eval in Javascript (except in some very hedge cases)

Comment: It's not part of your problem, but you should avoid "eval" at all costs...there is almost always a better way.

Comment: yup, but i strongly don't encourage using eval like that 
it's VERY unsafe :)
better use document.getElementById for this matter (lol i see i have been ninjad too :P)

Answer (score 0):

If the word is not in your array then you will get undefined.  If you type "Bo" then you will get undefined because "Bo" is not in your array.

You are calling the script with the KeyPress event.  If the user is trying to type Bob then this is what happens.

b -- b is in array, no problem

bo -- bo is not in array so undefined

bob -- javascript bombs at bo so you don't get this far.

Comment: Thank you, so how can I override that?

Comment: The if statement in Dany's post will handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you copied this from or why you are even considering doing it in this way.

Here is a better implementation. Tho next time please do some research before relying on others.

the HTML part

```
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td align="center" class="cleanuphtml-1">
              <form name="csrAlpha">
                Please insert your text below:<br />
                <input type="text" class="tb3" name="csrresult2" id="csrresult2" size="70" maxlength="120" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="translate()" />
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" onclick="csrAlpha.csrresult2.focus();" />

                <p>
                  <textarea name="csrresult" id="csrresult" class="tb7" cols="71" rows="10" value=""></textarea>
                </p>
              </form>
              </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and the JS part :

```
<script>
    var Words = {
        "b" : "Dadada",
        "bob" : "Robert",
        "flower" : "Banana",
        "brad" : "Chair"
    }


    function translate(){
        text = document.getElementById("csrresult2").value.toLowerCase();

        if(typeof Words[text] != "undefined")
            document.getElementById("csrresult").value=Words[text];
        else
            document.getElementById("csrresult").value="Text not found!";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: and Johnie is right, what i added will output a more informative error
also make sure you have in your html something like `<input type="text" id="fieldID">` or modify the `fieldID` accordingly

Comment: Hi Dany, I've been doing my research for 2 days and this is why I'm trying to get the information from a community who might know more than I do. I tried your code and the script doesn't work once I change it with what you suggested.

Comment: well, what i gave you is merely just to get you started :) i will modify my answer in a bit so that you'll have something to work with

Comment: Thanks! (You obviously can see that I'm a noob) :P

Comment: yes, well this should get you going, make sure you check the `id` that i added to your HTML tags so that i can use them easily in the JS code 
here is a helpful documentation website : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: Oh thanks Dany, that works perfectly! Here is a short noob question, how can I make sure that CAPS won't affect the result? Therefore whether it's Capitals or small letters it will be the same result.

Comment: you can use `.toLowerCase()` on the text that is fetched from the input box and convert it to lower case (i added the code above)

Comment: Awesome! Gawd I love Javascript! I need a good way to study it!

Comment: try this as a start : http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp
but when you become more experienced use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/

Comment: Thanks a lot Dany for your help! I'm really impressed how quick and professional you guys are! I'm glad I found this website!